# Eclipse Android Error: The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type MainActivity

Tags: android, eclipse

Eclipse Android Error: The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type MainActivity

I also have the error :

The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type MainActivity

Comment: import android.support.v7.app.ActionCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends ActionCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       
    }

Comment: How do i post my code normally. When i copy and paste it it looks like that

Comment: Edit the question and paste the code in it. Select the code that you pasted and hit `Ctrl+k`.

Comment: Add your code in question

Comment: import android.support.v7.app.ActionCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends ActionCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       
    }

Comment: It just comes out like that, even when i ctrl+K all the selected code. Thanks for your want to help by the way.

Comment: Paste the code in the question and not in the comments!

Comment: Click edit in your question and paste your code man!!!

Comment: Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).

I understand it thanks XD But when i insert the code and use cntrl K some words are redlined giving an error, and that sentence on top shows up. However, Prerak Sola gave me the solution, so thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve your error, change `ActionCompatActivity` to `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: Happy to help.. :) You can accept the answer than... ;)